# how to add many values to one key in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object `var obj = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};` I want to add multiple values or array of values to key1 or key2 e.g
  `var obj = {key1: "arrayOfValues", key2: "value2"};` is it possible? basically I want to send it to php for process.

Comment: `obj.key1 = "arrayOfValues"`. Is this what you mean? I’m failing to see where exactly you’re struggling. If you know the JS array syntax, this should be trivial.

Comment: yes may be I am not sure

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just define an array for the property:

```
var obj = {key1: ["val1", "val2", "val3"], key2: "value2"};
```

Or, assign it after the fact:

```
var obj = {key2: "value2"};
obj.key1 = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
```

Answer (score 17):

You can make objects in two ways.

1. Dot notation
2. Bracket notation

Also you can be define values in array with/without initial size.
For scenario one you can do the following in worst case scenario:

```
var obj = {}
obj.key1 = new Array();
obj.key2 = new Array();
// some codes related to your program
obj.key1.push(value1);
// codes ....
obj.key1.push(value);
// ... same for the rest of values that you want to add to key1 and other key-values
```

If you want to repeat the above codes in bracket notation, it will be like this

```
var obj = {}
obj['key1'] = new Array();
obj['key2'] = new Array();
// some codes related to your program
obj['key1'].push(value1);
// codes ....
obj['key1'].push(value);
// ... same for the rest of values that you want to add to key1 and other key-values
```

With bracket notation, you can use characters e.g 1,3,%, etc. that can't be used with dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same scenario and after scanning through many resources I found very elegant solution. Using Bracket Notation one can add multiple values to same key

```
let obj = {}
const demo = (str, objToAdd) => {
if(!obj[str]){
obj[str] = {}
}
const key = Object.keys(objToAdd)[0]
obj[str][key] = Object.values(objToAdd)[0]
}
```

Here important line is **obj[str][key] = Object.values(objToAdd)[0]**. This line will help you create object inside same key. **obj[str][key]** will create object inside object.
to add values call function as below

```
demo('first', {content: 'content1' } )
demo('first', {content2: 'content3' } )
```

> obj
>
> > first: {content: "content1", content2: "content3"}

Hopefully this will help someone.